Regarding formation energy
I am working on a MXene material Ti4N3Tx, where Tx is O, F, Cl, Br, S, Se, Te. I have to calculate its formation energy. The formation energy formula is E(Ti4N3Tx)-E(Ti4N3)-E(Tx) where E() is the total energy calculated from DFT. This is a 2D material. I am new to this so I am confused about how to calculate total energy for Tx. For example, should I take 2D Tx or its bulk form?

You need to look for stable structures of those elements. Stable structure of elements can be in form of molecule, 3D crystal or 2d crystal. It is not neccassary to be in form of 2D. I know that stable structure of O, F, Cl, Br are their molecular form which is $O_2, F_2, Cl_2, Br_2$. I am not familiar with VASP, but  I think it is similar to Quantum Espresso. To calculate, total energy of those molecules, you need to find their bond length and put them in large simple cube. Large simple cube helps to avoid from interactions of images. To find reference energy of element, After finding total energy of molecule, you have to divide it by two. Because molecules are consist of two elements.
In case of sulfur, most stable structrue should be its orthorhombic $(a-S_8)$ structure.

Thank you @gulomov2612. Could you please tell me is it enough to do non-magnetic calculation or i have to check all non magnetic and magnetic?
